# Flutter web app deployed by nodejs express which changes IP

Tags: node.js, flutter, express, web, static

I have a case where I have nodejs express as backend together with some frontend static content built by flutter in the same node.
The backend has some routes that flutter requests from. The device this runs on is a raspberry pi which might change IP. When flutter requests from the backend at some IP the whole app breaks when the raspi changes IP. Is there some way for the static content to dynamically request from the backend?

Backend with static content:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public-flutter')))

app.get('/someEndPath', (req, res) => {
   res.send('some response')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`app listening at http://localhost:4000`)
})
```

And Flutter client:

```
Future<String> getSomething() async {
   String url = '192.168.1.10:4000'; //<-- Works fine now, until the device changes IP
   final path = 'someEndPath';
   final Map<String, String> _headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-origin': '*'
   };
   http.Response response =
       await http.get(Uri.http(url, path), headers: _headers);
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     //print(response.body);
     return 'Something, not important';
   } else {
     print('no good response code');
     return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: You could use a dynamic DNS service that needs to be configured in your router. This will give you a domain, that changes the IP dynamically.

Comment: This device might or might not be connected to a router. If I decide to connect it to a router (it might need TCP/IP connection to other devices on the LAN side) the device will probably not need to change IP. The router will have the public IP and route to the device which then dont need to change. If I decide not to use a router then the device will not live in an environment with DNS service. Thanks for the answer. And, IP will be static for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

I can see now that I might have explained my problem poorly.
Anyhow, I now have my solution which I should have thought of sooner.
To get the IP dynamically (not hard coded) you can use Uri.base from Darts Uri class.
When client is a browser Uri.base is the current page.
Uri.base = window.location.href.
If the client is not a browser then it is the current workin directory.

```
Future<String> getSomething() async {
      String url = "${Uri.base.host}:${Uri.base.port}"; //<-- Solution
      final path = 'someEndPath';
      final Map<String, String> _headers = {
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Access-Control-Allow-origin': '*'
      };
      http.Response response =
          await http.get(Uri.http(url, path), headers: _headers);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return 'Something, not important';
      } else {
        print('no good response code');
        return null;
      }
    }
```

Be aware though, when developing locally flutter opens a chrome page with the url localhost:somePort. If your backend is not on the local computer you will need to hardcode the address, not like the solution.